# Bug when add bing Map control to WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I Create new Windows Phone 7 Project

Add the following references to my project:

-Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.Common.dll

-Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.dll

I insert BingMap Control in new Page

When I try to run on Emulator I get request

for add following reference to System.Windows.Browser.dll

Then add the reference to myproject from the following path:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\System.Windows.Browser.dll

now try again run App on emulator

but, emulator can not run App

too No error messages, only black screen on emulator

I expect problem comes from reference "System.Windows.Browser.dll" !

**What's problem? Is there a solution?**

Answer (score 2):

The Bing Map control you are using is a Silverlight control, and not optimised or coded for Windows Phone. I'm believe we should get a "proper" Windows Phone 7 Bing Map control in a future release of the tools.